# Refactoring to return multiple "informations"

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14

I have a type `T` provided by an external library and my virtual member function `f` declared as follows, which is overridden by many types in my program:

```
virtual T MyType1::f(input_t in);
virtual T MyType2::f(input_t in);
virtual T MyType3::f(input_t in);
```

Now I need a way to return an alternative, "mutually exclusive", information - which has nothing to do with `T` - to the caller depending on particular values of `in`. I cannot return any special value in the domain of `T` unfortunately, so I am afraid I'll have to refactor the declaration of `f()`.

I see these possibilities:

1. refactor `T` as `W MyType::f(input_t)`, where `W` is a wrapper
   around `T`, plus another member data and a cast operator to `T` so
   that I can use `W` as `T` everywhere as before except in the few
   places where I need to check the value of `u`, e.g. `struct W {T t;
   U u; operator T();};`
2. refactor `T` as a `variant <T, U>`
3. refactor `f` as `T MyType::f(input_t in, U& out);`
4. refactor `f` as `std::tuple<T, U> MyType::f(input_t);`

I think using a variant is the best option. What do you think?

Comment: This is exactly what #2 was made for.

Comment: If they're really mutually exclusive then #2 (or if suitable an exception) are probably the most sensible approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Combine 1 and 2:

you get the abstraction of one of your own types, you can much better document and test the invariants on the result type, and you can implement your result type abstraction in terms of `variant<T,U>`.

Compare the client code for these two pieces of code:

```
struct W
{
    operator T& (); // throws T_not_generated
    bool succeeeded() const;
private:
    variant <T, U> data;
};

virtual W MyType1::f(input_t in);
```

client code:

```
MyType1 a;
T t1 = a.f(in);
auto r2 = a.f(in);
if(r2.succeeded())
{
    T t2 = r2;
}
```

With this:

```
virtual variant <T, U> MyType1::f(input_t in);
```

client code:

```
MyType1 a;
try
{
    auto T1 boost::get<T>(a.f(in));
    auto r2 = a.f(in);
    if(??)
    {
        T t2 = boost::get<T>(r2);
    }
}
catch(const boost::<what's the error type?>& error)
{
    ///... 
}
```

My point is (**tldr**): you should consider abstracting away the handling of the result (and impose any invariants you need on it), but you can still use boost::variant behind the scene.

Comment: One possible downside: If `T` isn't (easily) copyable, then it's hard to get it "out" of the wrapper.

Comment: True, but there are ways around that, and you (well ... the OP) have full control over the API of the return type: you can extract a const reference from it (and impose _that_ API on the client code); you can also extract a pointer, a shared pointer and so on).